# How to implement a general-purpose list type?

Tags: algorithm, list, data-structures

Suppose you are developing a language that is intended to be used for scripting,  prototyping, as a macro language for application automation, or as an interactive calculator. It's dynamically typed, memory management is implicit, based on a garbage collection. In most cases, you do not expect users to use highly optimized algorithms or hand-picked and fine-tuned data structures. You want to provide a **general-purpose list** type that would have a decent performance on average. It must support all kinds of operations: iteration, random access by index, prepending and appending elements, insertion, deletion, mapping, filtering, membership testing, concatenation, splitting, reversing, sorting, cloning, extracting segments. It could be used both with small and large number of elements (but you can assume that it fits into physical memory). It's intended only for single-thread access and you need not care about thread safety. You expect users to use this general-purpose list type, no matter what is their scenario or usage pattern. Some users might want to use it as a sparse array, where most elements have some default value (e.g. 0), and only few elements have non-default values.

**What implementation would you choose?**

We assume that you can afford to invest significant development effort, so the solution need not be necessarily simple. For example, you could implement different ways of internal organization of data, and switch between them depending on number of elements or usage patterns. High performance is a more important goal than reducing memory consumption, so you can afford some memory overhead if it wins you performance.

Comment: Since your question is broad and not a specific implementation question, it may be better received on https://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Before reinventing the wheel, you might want to look at the works of other wheelwrights. Section 4 of this interesting paper discusses the core Lua datastructure: [The implementation of Lua 5.0](http://www.lua.org/doc/jucs05.pdf) by R. Ierusalimschy, L. H. de Figueiredo, W. Celes, Journal of Universal Computer Science 11 #7 (2005) 1159–1176. More information at http://www.lua.org/doc

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister This would be too broad for Programmers.